# Using form.submit() in client side GAS to transfer data to localhost

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-apps-script, post

I'm trying to create a pop-up browswer in GAS.
What I wanna do here is post some value to my local api and get response from it.
My code below doesn't work as I meant to and it's stuck in the screen in the picture.
Api doesn't get any request meaning post is not working successfully.
Any advice will be appreciated.

```
  if (cell_tick == true) {
    var tick_row = cell_pos.getRow();
    var date = new Date();
    sheet.getRange(tick_row, date_column).setValue(date).setNumberFormat('yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss'); 
    
    openTab()
    function openTab() {
    var js = "<script language='JavaScript'>\
    function openWindow()\
    {\
    myWindow = window.open('about:blank','theWindow','width=400,height=400');\
    }\
    </script>\
    <form method='POST' name='myForm' action='http://127.0.0.1:5000/' target='theWindow'>\
    <input type='text'>\
    <input type='button' onERASETHISClick='openWindow(); document.myForm.submit()' value='Open and after submit'>\
    </form>;\
    "
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
      //.setHeight(10)
      //.setWidth(100);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.');
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: You need to check browser console logs for errors. Does your request satisfy [tag:same-origin-policy]?

Answer (score -1):

Your form is in an iFrame, it basically exists in the internet on some server somewhere. It cannot post to localhost because that address is not public, it is local to your router. A good way to start is to read how client (the form) and the server (the app) can communicate with each other [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: The form is in the browser in the OP's computer. It can communicate with local ip, if there are no security restrictions.